# MSBuild Should not fail even if one specific NUnit test fail

Tags: msbuild, nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I have integrated continuous build process with Cruise Control. At the EOD, it generates a build report. If any NUnit test cases fail, then the build fails. We have written one specific test case and added it in a separate dll. We don't want our build to fail if any test case in that assembly fails. We are using MSBuild target, .proj files and cruise control, ccnet config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call NUnit two times: once for the tests you want to fail the build if the don't pass, then a second time to run the tests whose results you don't want to affect the build, e.g.,

```
<!-- Any failing tests in Assembly1.dll will cause the build to fail. -->
<Exec Command="nunit.exe Assembly1.dll" />

<!-- Any failing tests in Assembly2.dll won't fail the build because the ContinueOnError attribute is set to True. -->
<Exec Command="nunit.exe Assembly2.dll" ContinueOnError="True" />
```

Comment: If any of the tests fails, then by setting ContinueOnError to true will execute remaining tests in that assembly. But still Build fails, because my test fails. So ContinueInError = true is not working